# Mounting container filesystem into sidecar in k8s

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, persistent-volumes, overlayfs

I'd like to run `perf record` and `perf script` on a process running in a container in Kubernetes (actually on Openshift). Following the approach from [this blogpost](https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/profiling-applications-deployed-on-kubernetes-with-sidecar-injector/) I was able to get `perf record` working (in the sidecar). However the `perf script` cannot read symbols (in sidecar) because these are present only in the main container.

Therefore I'd like to mount the complete filesystem of the main container into the sidecar, e.g. under `/main` and then run `perf script --symfs=/main`. I don't want to copy the complete filesystem into an emptyDir. I've found another [nice blogpost](https://itnext.io/using-overlay-mounts-with-kubernetes-960375c05959) about using overlay filesystem; however IIUC I would need to create the overlay in the main container and I don't want to run that as a privileged container and require commands (like `mount`) to be present.

Is there any way to create sort of reverse mount, exposing a part of container to be mounted by other containers within the same pod?

Comment: Do you have any volumes configured (Google Cloud disk/ AWS/ Azure Disk etc.)? If not you can use hostpath https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath

Comment: I don't think hostpath would solve that. I don't need access to the underlying host, but to another container. And even if the other container is 'unzipped' somehwere it would be hard and fragile to guess where.